# Accessing multiple properties with one handle in MatLab

Tags: matlab, callback, position, handle

I'm looking to execute a callback on click of a plot, which then passes the position to the callback function. I know how to get the position and the callback on their own, but is there a way to do what I'm asking?

Comment: Do you have any example starting code or previous attempts, even if these caused errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't give you specific code because you didn't provide any in your question, but I think that you're asking for something like this:

```
h = figure;
v = get(h,{'Position','Units'})
```

`v` is a cell array – `v{1}` returns `[680   678   560   420]` and `v{2}` returns `'pixels'`. Similarly, you can set multiple properties of a handle by passing in two cell arrays:

```
set(h,{'Position','ToolBar'},{1.5*[680   678   560   420],'none'})
```

If you're doing animations or any operations that require many `get`/`set` calls, I've found that getting and setting properties in one call call can be faster.

Comment: I've never used the cell array syntax of `get` before. Nice.